# Who arranged the camera at the hospital?

Tags: plot-explanation, chronicle

In [*Chronicle* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706593/), Andrew was admitted in a hospital due to heavy burns.

[image: Camera Pointed at Hospital Bed]

Who arranged for a camera at the hospital to record him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Police did. Andrew was under arrest or under suspicion for mugging and for robbing the gas station. He's also hand cuffed. They called his father because Andrew was using his father's fire fighter suit. The camera is to keep him under watch and to use as evidence if needed.